# Making this UITableviewCell clickable

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, clickable

I'm currently working through this tutorial. http://thedarkdev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/web-service-apps-in-ios7-json-with.html. I have completed it and everything is working fine.

What I want is: Can you tell me how to make the entire cell clickable - the url should be the one specified in the JSON feed.

This is the .h:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
NSMutableArray *myObject;
// A dictionary object
NSDictionary *dictionary;
// Define keys
NSString *title;
NSString *thumbnail;
NSString *author;
NSString *permalink;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
title = @"title";
thumbnail = @"thumbnail";
author = @"author";
permalink = @"permalink";

myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios-blog.co.uk/?feed=json"]];

id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"author"];
    NSString *permalink_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"permalink"];

    NSLog(@"TITLE: %@",title_data);
    NSLog(@"THUMBNAIL: %@",thumbnail_data);
    NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",author_data);
    NSLog(@"URL: %@",permalink_data);

    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  title_data, title,
                  thumbnail_data, thumbnail,
                  author_data,author,
                  permalink_data,permalink,
                  nil];
    [myObject addObject:dictionary];
}
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableString *text;
    //text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:title]];
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
           [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:title]];

    NSMutableString *detail;
    detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@ ",
             [tmpDict objectForKey:author]];

    NSMutableString *url;
    images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
             [tmpDict objectForKey:permalink]];



    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= detail;

    return cell;
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The cell is already clickable, just add -

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Do whatever you like with indexpath.row
}
```

I hope you have set the tableview's delegate to self.

Comment: That is great when I NSlog text out. However when I try to do: NSLog(@"URL: %@",permalink_data); it comes up as build failed with: Use of undeclared identifier. How Do I get it to pass that NSString down to where I need to use it?

Comment: NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:permalink]);

Comment: permalink_data is a part of your dictionary, which is in turn an object in the myobject array.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:permalink]);
}
```